# Is it possible to implement websockets in DjangoRestFramework?

Tags: django, api, websocket, django-rest-framework

Is it the right practice to use WebSockets in DjangoRestFramework and if not which technology or framework could be used to do so ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. django-channels does this, and is a part of the django foundation. https://github.com/django/channels

Comment: @MichaelLindsay Yeah I know that I can use Django-channels but I'm just not sure whether it is the right practice or not

Comment: It’s the official recommended library.